# Creating alias for a class's member

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef

Say there is a class `test` with a member `void test::foo()`, we know we can create an alias for this class by `typedef test alt` (or the `using` command.)

Does c++ support aliasing class members in the following sense: `typedef test::foo() alt::fooatl();`, i.e., `alt.fooalt()` calls should correspond to a call to `test.foo()`?

Comment: A `typedef` can only alias types and not values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [p0945r0: "Generalizing alias declarations"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0945r0.html) would allow you to do that, but it was not yet moved forward at the latest meeting (Rapperswil).